# Wrong sql request done with a "has_many" for a subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sti

I'm trying to implement a "facebook like" like relationship.
I wanted to use inheritance for that, so here's my structure :

Likes with a user_id:integer attribute
|> PostsLike that inherits Like with a post_id:integer attribute

So here's my Like.rb model :

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And then my PostLike.rb model :

```
class Postlike < Like
  belongs_to :post
end
```

And finally I have a post model that will have multiple postlikes objects :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :postlikes

end
```

But here's my problem, when I go into irc and that :

1. I get a Post object :

   ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > @p = Post.all.first
2. I try to get postlikes of this object, here's the sql statement :

   SELECT `likes`.* FROM `likes` WHERE `likes`.`type` IN ('Postlike') AND `likes`.`post_id` = 310

So basically instead of doing

> postlikes.post_id

Rails' doing

> likes.post_id

Any idea to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord stores Like and Postlike object in the same table named "likes", and uses a column named "type" to save the class of the object. That explains the statement:

```
WHERE likes.type IN ('Postlike') AND likes.post_id = 310
```

There is no table `postlikes`

See "Single table inheritance" chapter at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: Right so why do I get this error : ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'likes.post_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `likes`.* FROM `likes`  WHERE `likes`.`type` IN ('Postlike') AND `l
ikes`.`post_id` = 310

Comment: Did you create a migration to add the column "post_id" to the table "likes", and run `rake db:migrate` after that ?

Comment: Ok yeah the problem was that I generated the postslike model with 'rails g model postslike ...' and then made it inherited from the like model so I forgot to migrate the column.
Thanks for that, stupid problem & question :)